# How do you log out of couchdb?

Tags: couchdb, logout

How are you supposed to log out of couchdb, I get a message telling me I can't reboot until I have logged out even though I have already logged out? I'm guessing it is something other than a user account that I have to log out of?

Kind regards
iFunc

Answer (score 3):

You can logout of a session like this:

To delete the session, you can do a

```
DELETE /_session
```

which will remove the session cookie.

An optional parameter  can be **"next"** which is provided to redirect the browser.

Possible return values can be the following:

```
200 OK (cookie removed)
302 Redirection (cookie removed) -- if "next" parameter was provided
```

For more information you can look over [here](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Session_API).

Comment: Can you do this faster directly in the browser?